# Как ПРАВИЛЬНО перевести сайт в другую кодировку?

Tags: utf-8, перекодировка

Выполнила следующие действия:
1) прописала в head другую кодировку
2) в NotePad пересохранила страничку в новой кодировке
Итог: заместо текста - каракули. 
 Сайт html+css+js без БД и PHP. Перевести с utf8 на win1251 (не знаю зачем , сказали надо сделать так). 
Как все-таки правильно перевести сайт, чтобы не было каракуль? Кто-нибудь знает? Спасибо!!!!

Comment: Оставить сайт в utf8 и сказать всем что перевести в другую кодировку его невозможно т.к. стандарт в интернете(как международной сущности) - utf8\unicode.

Comment: нужно все текстовые файлы перевести в кодировку cp1251 в linux я для этого использовал бы iconv и просто поиск всех файлов по шаблону. В windows я думаю тоже есть такая программа. Если же у вас есть php и вы ним умеете пользоваться то можно сделать это и через скрипт https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents

Comment: Спасибо! попробую!

Comment: А еще может потребоваться поменять конфиги Web-сервера, потому что там так же может быть указана кодировка, которую он сообщает в заголовке Content-type и которой браузеры верят. Либо она указана в файлах .htaccess, которые перекрывают собой глобальные конфиги веб-сервера

Comment: оо) не знала, спасибо! Посмотрю